# Values from last row overwrites other rows inside for loop

Tags: python, xml, for-loop

I'm converting an xml-file, but the last row from `childs.attrib` overwrites values from the other rows in certain columns.

```py
deCompressed = []
try:
    for childs in root:
        single = root.attrib
        single.update(childs.attrib)
        for child in childs:
            single.update(child.attrib)
            print(single)
            deCompressed.append(single)
```

`print(single)` shows the values as I would expect them to look. I think the problem is with the placement of the `update` statement because `print(childs.attrib)` gives me the values that are printed in all rows. I've tried moving the statements in and out of the `for-loop` and using `extend` instead of `append`, but with no luck so far.

I'm expecting an output like this:

```py
{DocumentType: 111, DepartmentCode:AAA, SubCustomer: 'A11'} 
{DocumentType: 123, DepartmentCode:BBB, SubCustomer: 'A12'} 
{DocumentType: 145, DepartmentCode:CCC, SubCustomer: 'A13'}
```

Instead I get this:

```py
{DocumentType: 145, DepartmentCode: CCC, SubCustomer: 'A13'} 
{DocumentType: 145, DepartmentCode: CCC, SubCustomer: 'A13'} 
{DocumentType: 145, DepartmentCode: CCC, SubCustomer: 'A13'}
```

The xml-input:

```
 <CompressedEntry SubCustomer="1687" LineNo="10000" ItemNo="18603" DepartmentCode="2105" CompressedEntryNo="33066">
    <DetailedEntry DeliveryRoute="L40294" DistributionDate="2019-11-22" Distributor="" Initials="auto" Location="" PercentageRate="" ProjectCode="'00057126960639343453" Quantity="1.00" Rate="21.10" Amount="21.10" System="pak. fak. s. 01" SystemDate="2019-11-23" TransactionText="" DieselTaxRate="0.00" DieselTaxAmount="0.00" EntryNo="1136851" ItemName="Hjemmelevering 250-499 g" Weight="498.00" />
  </CompressedEntry>


  <CompressedEntry SubCustomer="1687" LineNo="630000" ItemNo="73310" DepartmentCode="2647" CompressedEntryNo="33128">
    <DetailedEntry DeliveryRoute="321100" DistributionDate="2019-11-21" Distributor="" Initials="auto" Location="" PercentageRate="" ProjectCode="'00057126960623441509" Quantity="1.00" Rate="25.32" Amount="25.32" System="pak. fak. s. 02" SystemDate="2019-11-22" TransactionText="Pakkeshop retur" DieselTaxRate="0.00" DieselTaxAmount="0.00" EntryNo="1278046" ItemName="Pakkeshop retur 0-1.999 g" Weight="998.00" />
    <DetailedEntry DeliveryRoute="122200" DistributionDate="2019-11-22" Distributor="" Initials="auto" Location="" PercentageRate="" ProjectCode="'00057126960638137305" Quantity="1.00" Rate="25.32" Amount="25.32" System="pak. fak. s. 02" SystemDate="2019-11-23" TransactionText="Pakkeshop retur" DieselTaxRate="0.00" DieselTaxAmount="0.00" EntryNo="1278047" ItemName="Pakkeshop retur 0-1.999 g" Weight="1605.00" />
  </CompressedEntry>
```

The first CompressedEntry simply gets thrown away, and the last values with f.e. DepartmentCode: 2647 gets printed in all rows.

Comment: I've justed edited the output to show it more precisely. I expect an output where Customer and Subcustomer have different values in all rows. Instead, the value from the last row is overwriting the values in those two columns.

Comment: Can you share the xml and the complete code?

Comment: Try to add a valid subset of the XML to the post. Add the code section that loads the XML and parse it. What do you try to do here? Collect all attributes across XML path?

Comment: Looking inside the XML I dont see the Customer attribute. I do see the SubCustomer

Comment: Hey balderman. First of all: Thanks for taking a look at it! I've edited the original post, so it shows the XML-input. I'm simply trying to convert the format and naming of the xml-file. I inherited the code, and the format of the original XML-changed, so I'm try to adjust the code in Python.

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<SalesDocument DocumentType="Faktura" DocumentNo="80000538" PostingDate="2019-11-24" BillToCustNo="36721146-1020">
  <CompressedEntry SubCustomer="1687" LineNo="10000" ItemNo="18603" DepartmentCode="2105" CompressedEntryNo="33066">
    <DetailedEntry DeliveryRoute="L40294" DistributionDate="2019-11-22" Distributor="" Initials="auto" Location="" PercentageRate="" ProjectCode="'00057126960639343453" Quantity="1.00" Rate="21.10" Amount="21.10" System="pak. fak. s. 01" SystemDate="2019-11-23" TransactionText="" DieselTaxRate="0.00" DieselTaxAmount="0.00" EntryNo="1136851" ItemName="Hjemmelevering 250-499 g" Weight="498.00" />
  </CompressedEntry>
  <CompressedEntry SubCustomer="1687" LineNo="20000" ItemNo="18603" DepartmentCode="2115" CompressedEntryNo="33067">
    <DetailedEntry DeliveryRoute="B71907" DistributionDate="2019-11-22" Distributor="" Initials="auto" Location="" PercentageRate="" ProjectCode="'00057126960639323776" Quantity="1.00" Rate="21.10" Amount="21.10" System="pak. fak. s. 01" SystemDate="2019-11-23" TransactionText="" DieselTaxRate="0.00" DieselTaxAmount="0.00" EntryNo="1136852" ItemName="Hjemmelevering 250-499 g" Weight="498.00" />
  </CompressedEntry>
  <CompressedEntry SubCustomer="1687" LineNo="30000" ItemNo="18603" DepartmentCode="2140" CompressedEntryNo="33068">
    <DetailedEntry DeliveryRoute="B62349" DistributionDate="2019-11-20" Distributor="" Initials="auto" Location="" PercentageRate="" ProjectCode="'00057126960637514657" Quantity="1.00" Rate="21.10" Amount="21.10" System="pak. fak. s. 01" SystemDate="2019-11-21" TransactionText="" DieselTaxRate="0.00" DieselTaxAmount="0.00" EntryNo="1136853" ItemName="Hjemmelevering 250-499 g" Weight="498.00" />
  </CompressedEntry></SalesDocument>
'''
data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
doc_type = root.attrib['DocumentType']
entries = root.findall('.//CompressedEntry')
for entry in entries:
    data.append({'DocumentType': doc_type, 'SubCustomer': entry.attrib['SubCustomer'],
                 'DepartmentCode': entry.attrib['DepartmentCode']})
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'DocumentType': 'Faktura', 'SubCustomer': '1687', 'DepartmentCode': '2105'}, {'DocumentType': 'Faktura', 'SubCustomer': '1687', 'DepartmentCode': '2115'}, {'DocumentType': 'Faktura', 'SubCustomer': '1687', 'DepartmentCode': '2140'}]
```